# What is B. Stroutstrup referring to with the expression "incautious use" in this paragraph written on page 296 of his new book "TCPL" 4th edition?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

> ```
> class Request {
>     function<map<string,string>(const map<string,string>&)> oper; // operation
>     map<string,string> values; // arguments
>     map<string,string> results; // targets
> public:
>     Request(const string& s); // parse and store request
>     void execute()
>     {
>        [this]() { results=oper(values); } // do oper to values yielding results
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> Members are always captured by reference. That is, `[this]` implies that
>   members are accessed through `this` rather than copied into the lambda.
>   Unfortunately, `[this]` and `[=]` are incompatible. This implies that
>   **incautious use** can lead to race conditions in multi-threaded programs
>   (§42.4.6).

Comment: He's referring to possible **race conditions** when doing so, without exactly knowing what you do :) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's trying to make it clear that capturing `this` - whether implicitly or explicitly - does not copy the object that `this` designates. It can be surprising otherwise that a lambda such as `[=](){ return oper(values); }` is capturing a pointer to your object instead of capturing copies of `oper` and `values`.

Implicitly leaking pointers/references and spreading them around in multithreaded code is a recipe for disastrous UB. The standard doesn't define the behavior of programs with *data races*: multiple threads accessing a memory location (object) at potentially the same time, at least one of them performing a write.

Comment: Ok, but in this specific case, I think a race could only occur by the use of **one** object of class Request, in at least two threads. Is this correct?

Comment: @WakeupBrazil Yes, very much so.

Answer (score 2):

The prerequisites for that race condition are:

1. Multi-threading (as mentioned in the quote)
2. The object identified by `this` is accessed by more than one thread, during the lifetime of the lambda.

In general, you want to minimize the number of objects shared across multiple threads anyway, because they are the source of race conditions (with or without lambdas).  And, as usual, you can make the lambda use safe by taking a lock to protect access to the `this` object.

Comment: Basically what you're saying is that, for such a race to occur the same object of class Request has to be used in more than one thread. Is this a correct understanding of your answer?

Comment: Yes, either the object of type Request, or any of its subobjects.